# Java bytecode with Jasmin: why is the message not printed on the screen?

Tags: java, bytecode, jasmin

I recently became interested in Java bytecode and I created the following Hello World program.

The "Hello World" is printed, however I can't figure out why "Creating awesome object" isn't printed. Can you help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

```
.class public HelloWorld
.super java/lang/Object

.method public <init>()V
    .limit stack 2

    aload_0  ; push 'this' unto stack
    invokespecial java/lang/Object/<init>()V  ; invoke constructor

    getstatic java/lang/System/out Ljava/io/PrintStream;
    ldc "Creating awesome object!"
    invokevirtual java/io/PrintStream/println(Ljava/lang/String;)V

    return
.end method

.method public static main([Ljava/lang/String;)V
    .limit stack 2

    getstatic java/lang/System/out Ljava/io/PrintStream;
    ldc "Hello world"
    invokevirtual java/io/PrintStream/println(Ljava/lang/String;)V

    return
.end method
```

Comment: You're not actually executing the constructor anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about Java bytecode, but it seems to me you don't create an instance of `HelloWorld` in `main`. If you don't create an instance, the constructor does not get called, so there you have it. :)